# Ignore error LNK2001 (unresolved external symbol)

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a complex project that aim to port semi-automatically source code written for specific targets (microcontrollers) on PC, using then Visual Studio 2010/2012 to recompile it.

I use various intermediate files produced my micro-controller compilers to get a list of public methods and variables defined and I write them inside my **module.def** so that they can be visible by other DLLs.

Unfortunately some symbol have to be removed manually from source code before compiling for PC. So I am in the situation where my **module.def** contains some symbols that are not present anymore in my sources, and they generate error LNK2001 (unresolved external symbol).

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio Project to ignore LNK2001 errors in some way?

Comment: There's no way to *ignore* LNK2001, the linker literally cannot finish the linking step if it encounters unresolved symbols, so you won't have a library/executable at the end. Why can you not keep a version of your module.def for PC and remove the offending symbols in there?

Comment: Ok, it could be an idea, but there are many symbols that have to be removed manually in this case and I don't like it. Maybe I can try to perform a build, read the errors, modify the module.def accordingly and retry to build it.

Comment: You can automate that: stream the linkers output to file -> grep/sed the offending symbols -> stream them to file -> grep/sed them one by one from  module.def file.

Comment: Another option is to have a file that has dummy implementations for all the functions you removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cannot simply Ignore the linker - it is what assembles your final program from object files, static libraries, etc. Errors regarding "unresolved external symbols" means that the linker cannot find something it *needs* to build your executable.